# Run python that compiled with cython on any platform

Tags: python, cython

I convert my python script with cython to C file and then compile it with gcc.
Is it possible to run output file in any platform?

Comment: C in general needs to be compiled specifically for each platform. The code might be compatible, though.

Comment: Look into cross-compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Nop. Compiling a python extension (via Cython) under Windows will give you a `.pyd` (which is equivalent to a DLL) while you'll get a `.so` under Linux (well, it is not an extension matter, but ...). For example, if you built it under Linux, you will have to setup the [`MinGW Toolchain`](http://www.mingw.org/) under Windows, possibly adapt the code for some specific parts and finally recompile with this emulated version of gcc.

If you are targeting Win64, have a look at [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) instead of the regular MinGW project which is 32-bit only.

- [mingw-w64, targetting win32 + cross-compilatrion](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/)
- [mingw-w64, targetting win64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/)

Note: To make your code "relatively" portable, use `MACROs` like, for example:

```
#ifdef __WIN32__
// do my Windows specific stuff
#else
// ... handle others plateforms
#endif
```

Comment: I have a [Cython post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944883/verifying-compatibility-in-compiling-extension-types-and-using-them-with-cdef) you may be able to provide insight on.